404: NOT_FOUND - Code: DEPLOYMENT_NOT_FOUND when Deploying
I encountered the following error when trying to deploy my application:The site
I was deploying my application on Vercel. All tests passed during the deployment process. I also verified the deployment ID and ensured the necessary configurations were correctly set up. Additionally, I reviewed the documentation to check for any missing steps. I expected the deployment to proceed successfully, creating or updating the application as configured. Despite all the checks, I received the error.
